# Software & Updates and Software Updater won't start

Tags: updates, appcenter

I have some annyoing problem, the Software & Updates won't start when I click on it, but Software Center works fine. Also I noticed that sometimes, Software Updater automaticly turns on promting me with some updates, but when I click on "Install now" nothing happens. I can only press X to close it. This wasn't happening before and I don't know when it started.

I also searched trough search results but nothing worked.

When I run in terminal `software-properties-gtk` I get this result

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py:1511: Warning: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.42.2/./gobject/gsignal.c:1211: unable to lookup signal "window-state-event" of unloaded type 'GtkDialog'
  initialized, argv = Gtk.init_check(sys.argv)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py:1511: Warning: g_signal_add_emission_hook: assertion 'signal_id > 0' failed
  initialized, argv = Gtk.init_check(sys.argv)

** (software-properties-gtk:31131): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-jSJfg1tbIe: Connection refused
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 37, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.gtk.SoftwarePropertiesGtk import SoftwarePropertiesGtk
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 46, in <module>
    from .DialogCacheOutdated import DialogCacheOutdated
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/DialogCacheOutdated.py", line 28, in <module>
    from aptdaemon.gtk3widgets import AptErrorDialog, AptProgressDialog
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/gtk3widgets.py", line 42, in <module>
    gi.require_version("Vte", "2.91")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 83, in require_version
    (namespace, version))
ValueError: Namespace Vte not available for version 2.91
```

Similar result I also get when I run `update-manager`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those 2 applications are just graphical front ends for apt. This kind of thing is common with them. Open a terminal, and do:

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

This may fix or it will tell you what the underlying problem is.

Edit...

Found an old bug report regarding this. Probably a long shot but make sure  package gir1.2-vte-2.91 is installed.

Comment: OK I tried upgrade and this is the result.

`The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic-lts-utopic linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic
  linux-image-generic-lts-utopic linux-signed-image-generic-lts-utopic
  linux-tools-virtual-lts-xenial shim-signed
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 6 not to upgrade.`

Comment: You did update first as its important. That's fine, does software & updates work now .

Comment: It didn't worked, so I tried `sudo apt-get distro-update` and it upgraded those packages so now I'm getting `The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-34-generic
  linux-lts-xenial-tools-4.4.0-28 linux-signed-image-3.16.0-34-generic
  linux-tools-4.4.0-28-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.`

Comment: In my experience its never a good idea to do distribution upgrade, but it's done now. so fingers crossed. Do: sudo-apt-get autoremove as requested and then 'sudo apt-get --reinstall install python-apt update-manager'

Comment: Still not working. Even with reinstalling python-apt. Is there some command to get log output to see why doesn't open apps?

Comment: apt is working fine and you are upto date just this half bake python gui is the problem. I missed python3 off the list for re-install but looking at your output earlier its probably a good idea to do software-properties-gtk too. So sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3 software-properties-gtk

Comment: Still not working. I even restarted laptop. I guess I should stick with the `sudo apt-get update` for now on.

Comment: No idea then, the only other dependency is group policy but that'd be a different error. Could be a bug in pytho. or something custom you've done previously but --reinstall should've cleared that according to Ubuntu sources, doesn't mean that it has.  I always use apt-get update as its more reliable. If its a bug then it'll fix itself.

Comment: I also use it, but with Software & Updates you have aditional options, for example graphic drivers options. Thank you anyway!

Comment: whoops, just reading through and should've been python3-apt and apparently there is a python-apt. I dont think itll fix it but you should sudo apt-get install python3-apt to put it right, My mistake , had best intentions but didnt read my comment properly.  so sorry.

Comment: Still not working. I even deleted it and software center and reinstall it again, but still not working...

Comment: Ok this is akward situation...I haven't seen that part about instalation of gir1.2-vte-2.91. I just installed it and it fixed my problem. I even in the meantime reinstalled again elementary and again after ome time I got this problem. So the answer is to intall gir1.2-vte-2.91. Thank you a lot.